# Include html page in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make an administrative platform where someone can edit the text of an html file.

For this I made another page in which I'm thinking I could load the whole html file into a textarea.

I'm using Thymeleaf and Spring for this. and I DON'T want the html text to be rendered inside the textarea (most questions about this in stackoverflow want to render the html).

Here's an example:

Page (text) I want to be inside the text area:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
              href="../../static/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="document.f.username.focus();">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> Thymeleaf -
                        Plain </a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a th:href="@{/}" href="home.html"> Home </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert">You have been logged out</p>
                <p th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">There was an error, please try again</p>
                <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>
                <form id="login" name="login" th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" action="/doLogin" method="POST">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />


    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I want the user to be able to edit exactly that so I want to include that text in a texarea like this:

```
<div class="content">
                <h1>Editing page index.html</h1>
                <h2>HTML code: </h2>
                <textarea th:text="${param.clic[0]}">//Here is where i need help
                </textarea>
            </div>
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you for you help! If you need any more details I'll be happy to give them

Comment: [Textarea elements](http://html5index.org/DOM%20-%20HTMLTextAreaElement.html) do not have a text attribute. You may wish to try `th:value` or possibly `th:defaultValue` instead.

Comment: Cancel that, sorry. I just found where th:text inserts text between the tags.

Comment: @Traktor53 Yup, thanks. Thymeleaf takes care of it for me.

Comment: I tried using th:include instead of th:text and it does shows me the page however it ignores the th tags inside the original page. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you pass html-text from controller to view?

Comment: I just tried to build example and `textarea` shows html code well. I passed text thru `th:text`.

Comment: The text is stored in html files. Tried th:text and instead of just giving me the text like expected (not replacing the html):

<div id="modalWindowWrapper">

            <div th:replace="fragments/fragment_index :: abrirExecutive">
            </div>

           
            <div th:replace="fragments/fragment_index :: inicioSesion">
            </div>

</div>

It actually replaced that html with the fragments. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Hello Juan Carlos, did you solve the problem? I would like to know how you handled it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting as answer since it worked for me, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things didn't work out using th:text nor th:utext however what I did was to read the document.html as a text file on java and then placed the text on the textarea. I used some most of the code posted on: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example

Here I leave my full code on java:

```
@Value("${application.thymeleaf.templatesdir}")
    String path;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            //Clic is added as parameter on the url
            String documento = path + request.getParameter("clic") + ".html";
            StringBuilder cad = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(documento));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                cad.append(sCurrentLine + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Exception...
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Error
            }
        }

        model.put("text", cad.toString());
        return "admin/editaUnaPagina";
```

And on HTML I have this:

```
<form th:action="@{/saveHtml}" method="POST">
                    <h2>HTML code:</h2>
                    <textarea class="textarea" th:text="${text}" name="text">
                    </textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="SAVE"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="clic" th:value="${param.clic[0]}" />
                    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

The "clic" parameter on the java code is named exactly like the document's name.

The value of application.thymeleaf.templatesdir is established by me on my application.properties and it looks like this:

application.thymeleaf.templatesdir = resources/templates/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an `th:utext` tag for text with html.

Here is official documentation - [unescaped text](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text)

Comment: Tried it, doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for